# Scraping Amazon review issue in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyr, rvest

I am trying to scrape a Amazon product page, more specifically the **review** section.

I have tried different codes, one of them is this:

```
if(!"pacman" %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"]) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(rvest, dplyr, tidyr, stringr)

# Airpods
asin_code <- "B09JQMJHXY"

url <- paste0("https://www.amazon.com/dp/", asin_code)
doc <- read_html(url)

#obtain the text in the node, remove "\n" from the text, and remove white space
prod <- html_nodes(doc, "#productTitle") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub("\n", "", .) %>% 
  trimws()

prod
```

This scrapes only the title, but if I fix this, the rest will be okay I guess.

So the **problem** is the fact that when I tried first time I got the right output (which is the title).

After running the same code 15 min later, I get `character(0)`.
**What may cause this?**

Does Amazon have blocked my IP, or sth similar?

*R version 4.3.2*

Comment: when doing this, I get a robot check, not even the title

Comment: 'To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.\n        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)

page <- "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09JQMJHXY" |> 
  read_html()

page |> 
  html_elements(".a-section.review.cr-desktop-review-page-0") |> 
  map_dfr(~ tibble(
    title = html_element(.x, ".cr-original-review-content") |> 
      html_text2(),
    rating = html_element(.x, ".a-icon-alt") |> 
      html_text2(), 
    review = html_element(.x, ".reviewText") |>  
      html_text2(),
    date = html_element(.x, ".review-date") |> 
      html_text2()
  ))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  title                                                       rating review date 
  <chr>                                                       <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1 AirPod Pro                                                  5.0 o… Excel… Revi…
2 10/10 llegó como tenía que llegar                           5.0 o… Muy b… Revi…
3 Buenos audifonos.                                           5.0 o… Muy b… Revi…
4 Son buenos, pero me salieron con un error, pero Apple con … 4.0 o… Este … Revi…
5 Cómodos y súper fáciles de usar                             5.0 o… Son l… Revi…
```